# spring boot gradle proyecto multi modulo extraño error NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Tengo un problema algo extraño y seguro a alguno le ha pasado esto, el caso es este: tengo tres módulos que son Servicios web están dentro de un proyecto springboot con gradle.

- módulos:

  1. Commons.
  2. Hr Collab.

Hr y Collab dependen de Commons:

**Collab:** `http://localhost:8080/**collab-api**/auth/commons/motivation/category/91ea125f-a17d-40b6-adb3-6f0de414bf36`

**HR:** `http://localhost:8081/**hr-api**/auth/commons/motivation/category/91ea125f-a17d-40b6-adb3-6f0de414bf36`

***/auth/commons/motivation/category/91ea125f-a17d-40b6-adb3-6f0de414bf36***

Como pueden ver el servicio es el mismo en collab y en hr solo que acceden de diferente modulo y pasan a través del mismo servicio de commons, cuando se realiza esto desde:

```
collab-api
```

No tengo problemas pero cuando lo hago desde

```
hr-api
```

Obtengo un exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: xxx.WsMotivationCategory.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V

El error ocurre justo cuando la variable result que es un LinkedHashSet trata de agregar un nuevo elemento a la pila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia sera bien recibida muchas gracias Capos!

Comment: Cuales son las propiedades de MotivationQuestionOption

Comment: el problema no es con ese objeto sino cuando se quiere hacer uso del metodo add en la variable result, es un simple linkedHashSet